# How do I convert a physical mac to a Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I convert my OS X Lion into a VMware virtual machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/336393/can-i-convert-my-os-x-lion-into-a-vmware-virtual-machine)

Seems to be easy to do from Windows or Linux, but not finding much on how to do it with a mac.

VMWare would be preferable, but VirtualBox would do too.

Comment: You are allowed to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software within virtual operating system environments **on each Mac Computer you own or control that is already running the Apple Software**. -- OS X EULA, for this reason third-party software does not support running it virtually.